# "Missing Leadstone Jetpack" while attempting to craft it with Logistics Pipes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm having strange issues with Logistics Pipes. I'm trying to automate crafting a jetpack, but something weird is going on. Please check the images below.

Basically, when I attempt to request a jetpack from the request table, it says "missing 1 leadstone jetpack", which is exactly what I want to craft. I checked several times, the crafting pipe is set up and connected properly. The crafting pipes right next to it are working fine.

The same thing happens when I try to request a Leadstone Thruster (needed for the jetpack), or a Steam Dynamo (needed for thrusters).

Any idea what might be wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What cable did you put in front of the auto crafting table?

Comment: You mean what pipe? It's just a normal crafting pipe.

Comment: I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/feedthebeast/comments/5xvfof/cant_craft_a_jetpack_using_logistics_pipes/dem895c?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) - unsure if it helps.

Comment: Voting to leave this question open. As per the meta posts: [Minecraft crash questions should be made off-topic: yes/no?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11015/4797), [Why just ban Minecraft modding tech support?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10568/4797) and [What exactly is technical support?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11015/4797) only crash issues and other technical issues related to running modded Minecraft are off-topic. Modded Minecraft gameplay-related issues are on-topic.